# PHP getting the value of the highest dynamic select

Tags: php, select, post

I have a series of selects that contain world regions.

For instance select r0 would contain

```
Africa
North America
Europe
```

When the user selects North America, a new select named r1 would appear with the following values:

```
Canada
United States
Mexico
```

Then the user would select US, r2 would appear with the states and so on.

As the data structure allows, currently, there can be up to 5 boxes (r0-r4)

I am trying to figure out how in php I can determine that there are 4 or 5 selects, and save that value of the highest number select to the database.

Am I going at this the wrong way?

Currently, I don't have any code written, because I'm not sure how to test the range of the $_POST["r#"] arrays, but was thinking something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while (isset($_POST['r'.$i])) {
    $highest_value = $_POST['r'.$i];
    $i++;
}

?>
```

is there a better way?

Comment: If you're getting the highest value, going from top to bottom would be faster (if it's highly populated), and then break on the first you find.  Also, try using a `<select name="region">` instead of what'ever you're doing, then you would just do `$_POST['region']`.

Comment: After the user has selected the locality, the value I'm looking to save can be in r2-r5, but not all will have up to r5. I need to find out how to determine what the highest number of r selects are created, then what the last r select's value is

Comment: Add another hidden field called `maxSelect` and update its value whenever you enable a new select with the number of the select you are currently displaying.  On the server side make sure the number is in the proper range.

Comment: @Yaniro, good idea. With the loop I wrote above, there was no control and could easily get stuck in an infinite loop.  Your idea fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

I will try this :

```
$Value = null;
for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if(isset($_POST['r'.$i]) AND $_POST['r'.$i]){
        $Value = $_POST['r'.$i];
        break;
    }
}
```

I did not test it out.

Comment: the only problem with that is that the number of selects will not always be 5 (I know that does not count on 5), and I'm not sure if I will need to expand to more than 5. I was hoping to test for a more dynamic way to determine the actual number of selects.

Comment: Ahhhh ... then create a new field inside your form. This field, hidden, will contain the count you have and pass it to your php script. So : it is dynamic, unlimited field, and you just test out in PHP the field to be sure he isn't empty or whatever !